# Python - Return substring of string that can change

Tags: python, regex

I have a txt file that has a lot of data, and on each line there are 2 pieces of data I need to collect that are seperated by a hyphen.

Example:

```
Deleted User#0000 - ['000000000003959552', '000000000003959553', '000000000003959554']
```

I have a function that will be searching the text file for one of the numbers on the RIGHT of the hypen. So if I search for: 000000000003959553 - I want to return: Deleted User#0000 and assign it to a var.

The values will change, but they will always be separated by a hyphen, or any other identifier I want to set as.

What can I do to accomplish this?

Comment: `for line in file: if "000000000003959553" in line: print(line[:line.find('-')].strip())`?

Answer (score 1):

We can try parsing the right side of each line as a list, and iterating to see if it contains the value we are searching for. If it does, we return the left side.

```py
from ast import literal_eval

def search_for_value(value):
    for line in file:
        left, right = line.split(' - ')
        for id in literal_eval(right):
            if id == value:
                return left
```

Answer (score 0):

You can match the regular expression

```
(?m)^.+(?= +- +\[.*'000000000003959553')
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/R5klLp/1).

`(?m)` sets the *multiline flag*, causing `^` to match the start of a line, rather than the start of the string (and `$` to match the end of line, rather than the end of the string).

`^.+` matches one or more characters at the beginning of a line.

`(?= +- +\[.*'000000000003959553')` is a *positive lookahead* that requires the match to be followed by one or more spaces, a hyphen, one or more space, `[`, zero or more characters, a single quote, `000000000003959553` and lastly, another single quote.

Comment: You might also use a negated character class to prevent the backtracking from the 2 times `.+` like `(?m)^[^-\n]*(?= +- +\[[^][]*'000000000003959553')`

Comment: @The Bird #4, thanks. Mr. Sandman beckons. Will look at that in the morn.